# How to assign ansible variable output to another variable from nested list

Tags: ansible, jsonpath, ansible-facts, ansible-template, jmespath

I need help to perform join operation of Ansible task output. I have output as below:

```json
{
    "ansible_facts": {
        "server_and_its_status": [
            {
                "name": "server1",
                "session": "enabled"
            },
            {
                "name": "server2",
                "session": "enabled"
            }
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

I want the output to be formatted as:

```yaml
{ 
"server1": "enabled"
"server2": "enabled"
}
```

I have tried many ways to get the output from my task as below but no luck:

```yaml
- name: Get the server details
  set_fact:
    server_and_its_status: "{{ jsondata1 | json_query('data.member[].nodes[].{name: name, session: sessionStatus}') | join(':','name','session') }}"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use filter [items2dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries), e.g.

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      srv_stat: "{{ server_and_its_status|
                    items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='session') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  srv_stat:
    server1: enabled
    server2: enabled
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimit for an perfect solution. It worked as expected !!